# how to make a standard web site design for every browser

Tags: php, html

i am using WYSIWYG Web builder for designing my web site using php amd mysql .I have set the default page size resolution to 1024x768 .
the pages work well in the chrome browser but pages distort look wise in mozilla(latest vers.)
The problem is with the screen size also , when i open the web page on my laptop
(15" screen ), i cannot view a proper site even in chrome this time .

pls suggest any quick remedies to my problem !!

Thanks

Comment: This is a career-defining question! Can you refine your search to some specific aspect of your design, perhaps showing some specific CSS and markup you have used, and exactly what you want to achieve, but haven't been able to?

Comment: Dont you hear the name [CSS](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CIkBEBYwCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FStyle%2FCSS%2FOverview.en.html&ei=ZbzeT8KMF8mtrAfOvP3BDQ&usg=AFQjCNG0KtTkKX-ScjZZz-oSUtvtet6PAw)?

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code so I can see what is your WYSIWYG Web builder doing and perhaps correct it ?

Comment: Use a CSS reset and conditonal IE style sheets

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly the kind of "answer" you are looking for, but I wanted to put it here as an "answer" in hopes that it will come across as a legitimate piece of advice.

If cross-browser support is important to the success of your project, you should weigh your skills and time against the option of hiring a professional. It is seriously complicated, however there are talented folks in almost every market who specialize in cross-browser design.

Comment: Thanks guys ! .....I'll consider resolving it by going deep into "CSS"